# Grid cell edges for regions of discrete data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I have a 2d-array of integers defining regions on a grid. I would like to draw edges on the borders between different regions.

I tried with contour (commented out in the code) but that gave me 2 undesirable results:

1. It draws multiple lines if there is a big difference between region ids
2. The contour lines are not on the cell boundaries.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nproc = 5
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2],
    [3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1],
])

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', nproc)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data, vmin=0, vmax=nproc-1, cmap=cmap)

plt.autoscale(tight=True)
colorbar = plt.colorbar(heatmap)

colorbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
"""
contour = plt.contour(data, range(0, nproc),
                      colors='k', linestyles='solid')
"""

for j, lab in enumerate(['$%d$' % i for i in range(0, nproc)]):
    colorbar.ax.text(1.2, (2 * j + 1) / float(nproc*2),
                     lab, ha='left', va='center')

plt.savefig('output.pdf')
```

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73353617/matplotlib-contour-plot-does-not-extract-exact-contours/73390362#73390362